# Jquery UI date picker with reservation dates (Date range)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used Jquery UI date picker in two fields ie book_from and book_to for reservation.

When I get focus on book_from only the dates less than book_to and dates greater or equal to today's date must shown in the date picker of book_from.

**ie**

if book_from = null and book_to=2012-04-10

Then book_from date picker there should only be greater than today's date (2012-03-18) and less than 2012-04-10 (book_to) (not even 2012-04-10)

and if I get focus on book_to then in date picker of book_to only dates greater than today's date + greater than book_from date

**ie**

if book_from = 2012-04-05

then book_to date picker only shows greater than today's date (2012-03-18) and greater than 2012-04-05 (not even 2012-04-05)

Please help me if anybody knows how to do it..

Comment: What have you tried? This question has been answered in different forms before, have you tried searching for dependent date pickers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling many hours I have finally found the solution, it was the date range datepicker for reservation :).I was not just getting the term to explain my problem. Here is the solution

```
$('#book_from, #book_to').datepicker({
       minDate: 0,
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
function customRange(input) {

    if (input.id == 'book_to') {
        var minDate = new Date($('#book_from').val());
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1)

        return {
            minDate: minDate

        };
    }
    else  if(input.id == 'book_from') {
        var maxDate = new Date($('#book_to').val());
        maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-1)

        return {
            maxDate: maxDate

        };
    }

    return {}

}
```

Comment: errrrr here's a jsbin if this helps at all http://jsbin.com/beyalol/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output